# Cracks in cedar balusters and railings

Tags: wood, porch, rot, cedar, baluster

We installed a new porch with cedar balusters and railings.  It was expensive so we want to make sure it is done right.

There are quite a few cracks in the both the bottom rails and the balusters.  Two pictures below for examples.

Will paint be sufficient protection to prevent water from getting in the cracks and causing rot?  Or should we have the cracked balusters and railings replaced?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cedar will rot, paint or no paint, if exposed to weather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paint would be sufficient.

Small cracks are pretty normal on any given piece of lumber, so that is not concerning. Just be sure to properly clean the surfaces before painting so it adheres well.

Comment: @minou I concur. Looking at the existing paint, it would seem that the whole thing needs a quality coat of paint. You shouldn't see grain through the paint. Is that primer?

Comment: Yeah, just primer so far.  Paint job is still to come.  Thanks both for the reassurance.